# Is there a recommended way to backup photos on an iMac

Tags: iphone, ipad, imac, photos

I have about 2,000 photos that I don't want to lose no matter what happens. I'm not even sure where the original images are stored. The images were taken by various iPhones I've had over the years. If I open the Photos app on my iMac I can see all my images. Same with my iPad and iPhone. Is there a recommended way to back up these photos or, since I see them on all 3 devices, are they already backed up. My iMac is 10 years old and I'm afraid my disk will crash before I can get a new iMac.

Comment: Using terms like "best way" and "best easy way" make for an opinionated answer. It could be said that an _easy way_ to keep a Mac backed up is to use **Time Machine**, but is it the _best easy way_?

Comment: thanks. i slightly changed my question. if it still seems wrong please let me know!

Comment: Your _title_ still says "What is best way to backup photos on an iMac" and "best way" is an opinion. Anyway, since Apple has both **Time Machine** and **iCloud**, available for the Mac, it could be said that either are a recommended way to backup. Personally, I use **Time Machine** as well as making copies of what I do not want to loose to multiple sets of DVDs and store them in different locations, e.g. my fire proof safe at home, my safety deposit box at the bank. Also have multiple copies of things on multiple HDDs stored in my fire proof safe. I do not use **iCloud**.

Comment: I changed my title. Thanks for your input and the information you shared.  Would you mind expounding on why you don't use icloud?

Comment: I have far to much to store in the cloud, nor would I even if I only had a little. I will never entrust my data storage to someone else on the cloud, not even **Apple**. I'd rather control it locally or loose it; however, I have adequate redundancy controlled locally in multiple locations and storage media that I'm not worried about loosing it. I have no less then three copies of everything on multiple HDDs and DVDs for the most important stuff. I keep a database of everything so I can easily search for something and know where it's stored to easily retrieve it.

Comment: thanks... it sounds like you ar covered...

Comment: BTW I use [DiskCatalogMaker](https://diskcatalogmaker.com) to catalog everything. (I'm not affiliated with its developer, just a satisfied customer!)

Comment: DiskCatalogMaker sure is a nice app and fast too. Thanks for the tip!